# For loop where the previous value is used within equation

Tags: matlab

I want to do a for loop where the values within an array  are summed, so as the 1st value is still the same the 2nd value becomes the sum of the 1st and 2nd values within array, the 3rd becomes the sum of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd values within array etc.

```
den_p = 0;

for lp = 1 : bars-1
   den_p =  den_p + lCubed_p(1,lp)./In_p(1,lp)
   den_w = lCubed_w./In_w;
end
```

The values that are produced are correct but I want to store them within an array of length lp, I tried doing :

```
den_p = 0;
for lp = 1 : bars-1
  den_p(1,lp) =  den_p(1,lp) + lCubed_p(1,lp)./In_p(1,lp)
  den_w = lCubed_w./In_w;
end
```

but the function can't call itself within itself.

Comment: Try CUMSUM - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html ? That is "cumsum(lCubed_p./In_p)" ? What you gonna do with den_w is some other issue.

Comment: Initialise `den_lp` as `den_lp=zeros(1,bars-1)` before the for loop to create the elements which you will then modify.

Comment: Your Code does not match the description. What is the purpose of calculating a constant within the loop? `den_w = lCubed_w./In_w;`

Answer (score 0):

Vectorising should do you well here, both speed-wise and will solve your problem if I understood it correctly.

```
%example for den_p only as no explanation given for requirements for den_w

lp = 1:bars-1;
den_p = zeros(1,bars-1); %generate an empty array in the right size

%kept vector operation and cumulative sum separated for ease of understanding
%if unfamiliar with vectorising 
den_p(1,lp) = lCubed_p(1,lp)./In_p(1,lp); %vectorised assignment to array

den_p(1,lp) = cumsum(den_p(1,lp),2); %Cumulative sum along 2nd dimension
```

See [cumsum()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) for more info

Hope this helps